# Displaying map view with navigation?.push(mapView) and not seeing anything pop up

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, mapkit, mkmapview

I am trying to display a MapKit view when the user clicks a button where MapScreen is of class UIViewController and MKMapKitdelegate.

When I perform this sender on the UIButton all I am getting is the background color of the other screens in my TabBarController.

```
let mapController = MapScreen()
navigationController?.pushViewController(mapController, animated: true)
```

I would expect to see the map as is defined in MapScreen(). I am using this same method to display many other view controllers and it works great.

Comment: Have you verified that `navigationController` isn't `nil`? Is the view controller in a navigation controller?

Comment: Hey! Could you please share more details? `MapScreen` implementation details would be nice to see. It seems that `MkMapView` was not properly added to view hierarchy.

Comment: I am putting a break here and am getting Map MKMapView? nil none, so I think that it was not added to the view correctly. I am just doing a control click and drag from the mainStoryboard such that: @IBOutlet weak var Map: MKMapView!

Comment: @MikePerhats Please do not post code and other details in comments. [Edit] your question and put all relevant info there.

Comment: http://www.programmingios.net/dont-make-a-new-instance-by-mistake-2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your view controller defined in storyboard you should not use plain `init` to initialize an object. As [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621359-init) states:

> When using a storyboard to define your view controller and its associated views, you never initialize your view controller class directly. Instead, view controllers are instantiated by the storyboard either automatically when a segue is triggered or programmatically when your app calls the `instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)` method of a storyboard object. When instantiating a view controller from a storyboard, iOS initializes the new view controller by calling its `init(coder:)` method instead of this method and sets the `nibName` property to a nib file stored inside the storyboard.

So, In order to create view controller from storyboard you should call `instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)` function of `UIStoryboard` object:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MainStoryboard", bundle: .main)
let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Your view controller identifier")
```

Hope this helps.